# Excel UDF for VLOOKUP(MATCH()) that uses structured table references

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions, vba

I'm trying to build an Excel user defined function `VLOOKUP_NAME(value, table, column_name)` that would implement:

```
VLOOKUP(value, table, MATCH(column_name, table[#Headers], FALSE), FALSE)
```

How do I do this in VBA? VBA doesn't seem to accept structured references like `table[#Headers]`.

Also, I'd be interested in knowing about the performance consequences of implementing this as a UDF as well.

Also, the reason I'm doing this is to replace a ton of ugly formulas with more readable formulas. Other better suggestions to achieve this are welcome.

Comment: Could you post the code you are using and explain specifically where you are stuck?

Comment: `table[#headers]` might be `Array("headerA","headerB","headerC")` in VBA

Comment: @JimmyPena: Under Function VLookup_Name(value, table, column_name), I tried: VLookup_Name = WorksheetFunction.VLOOKUP(value, table, WorksheetFunction.MATCH(column_name, table[#Headers], FALSE), FALSE)

Comment: What is `table[#Headers]` ?  It's not valid VBA, so what is it meant to represent?

Comment: It's a structured reference (valid in formulas). See https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-HA010155686.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with that structured reference syntax, but have you tried constructing the formula and using the worksheet `Evaluate()` method?

Here's a simple example:

```
Function TestEval(s1 As String, s2 As String)
    TestEval = Application.Caller.Parent.Evaluate(s1 & "/" & s2)
End Function
```

EDIT: After checking out the whole structured table thing, this seems to work:

```
Function TableLookup(val, tbl As Range, colName As String)
    Dim indx, rv
    indx = Application.Match(colName, tbl.Rows(1).Offset(-1, 0), 0)

    If Not IsError(indx) Then
        rv = Application.VLookup(val, tbl, indx, False)
        TableLookup = IIf(IsError(rv), "Not found", rv)
    Else
        TableLookup = "Col??"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: "Application.FOO" is going to be very handy, didn't know about this. And thanks for the full example, with the Rows().Offset, works great!